# How do I use the same property for two classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, properties, game-center

Basically i have five properties in a class called MyClassXY. In my MyClassXY.m I have a nstimer that gets called every 0.1 seconds and sets these properties to whatever value i set these properites to be from the Main_game_scene viewcontroller class. But I allocated MyClassXY in the Main_Select_level viewcontroller. Is the only way to fix this to pass the MyClassXY object from Main_Select_level to the Main_game_scene viewcontroller, or is there some way to solve this. I don't want to allocate a whole new MyClassXY object becouse it has a whole bunch of other variables that both classes need to interact with. Maybe class methods?

Sorry for newbie question.

Comment: Not really getting your problem. Is the timer only there to copy values from one class to another because you aren't sure how else to do it?

Comment: ohh, maybe i should have said it but, im making a multiplayer game using Gamecenter. I mean set these members of a struct to the value of the property, and then send the struct to the other device every 0.1 seconds.

Comment: So what's wrong with passing the instance?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, i don't know how i should do it.

Comment: how do i pass the instance?

Comment: Does the select level controller not push the game scene controller, or have a segue?

Comment: ViewController *viewcont = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [view2 presentViewController:viewcont animated:NO completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your MyClassXY to be a [singleton](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/).  Then you can get a reference to it anywhere you need in your program, but it will always be the same instance. For example, [UIApplication sharedApplication] is a singleton.

Comment: How do I add data to the singleton? Cant find it anywhere in the guide.

Comment: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/
You use: YourClass *c = [YourClass sharedInstance];

Comment: Just add properties to the class in the .h file as you would any other

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how Main_game_scene and Main_Select_level are related. Is there a segue from the first to the second? Modal or Push? Which one come first? Then you can pass the object from the source view controller to the destination view controller.
If you need one (and one only) instance of class MyClassXY for all your app, use a Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You currently create and present the game using:

```
ViewController *viewcont = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[view2 presentViewController:viewcont animated:NO completion:nil];
```

to pass the class which manages your game center interaction (using your timer), all you need to do is:

```
ViewController *viewcont = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
viewcont.scoreController = self.scoreController;

[view2 presentViewController:viewcont animated:NO completion:nil];
```

where `scoreController` is a property on `ViewController` to hold the reference to your game center interaction controller and `self.scoreController` is the instance of that class that you created earlier.